# $$ and $ in PrototypeJs

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am new to PrototypeJs. I am searching for different tutorials to increase my knowledge for this. Suddenly I observed that Magento also using Prototype with double $$ (dollar signs) instead single $ (dollar sign). So what is the different between single and double dollar sign in prototype. Assume the following example

```
function test(){
    div = $("div");
    alert(div.innerHTML);
}
```

but in magento (also found in many tutorials, peoples are using $$), like

```
function test(){
    div = $$("div");
    alert(div.innerHTML);
}
```

Any body to help me out with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That says:

```
 $('div') // document.querySelector('div') <----single first element in collection
$$('div') // document.querySelectorAll('div') <----collection of all divs
```

[$$ prototype docs.](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/)

Answer (score 1):

"$" stands for select by ID.

"$$" stands for select by class and by tag.

For more info: http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/get_started_with_prototype/

Comment: No, this is wrong. The accepted answer is correct.